# String manipulations

Tags: c, string

Is there a proper way to just copy a part of a string after a certain point.

```
Party City 1422 Evergreen Street
```

I use strpbrk() to copy the name out, I could always just tokenize it by white space but is there a string process or technique where I can copy out a specific section of a string besides from the beginning like copy just [1422 Evergreen Street] or delete the first portion of the string?

Comment: Do you mean by giving the starting position and the length? As your last sentence sounds like you want to specify the string to copy, but then you know it already.

Comment: By 'string' you mean character array?  How do you want to identify the splitting point?  Whitespace, position, string match?

Comment: @forsvarir I was intending the splitting point to be at the 1422

Comment: There are regex libraries available for C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to specify it by starting position and length, you can always use strncpy and a bit of pointer arithmetic.

**EDIT:** When you know the starting string you can use

```
char *pos = strstr(src, "1422");
strcpy(dst, pos);
```

Comment: I was going to do that but having trouble with the syntax, I thought strncpy only copied a n length

Comment: when you want to copy till the end you can use strcpy and just adjust the starting position by using strcpy(pDst, pSrc+iStart).

Comment: Oups I didn't see this previous answer... I added a code snippet to my answer for an example on how to use strncpy starting from a given index.

Comment: ah okay I didn't know we could adjust the second parameter

Comment: Bad answer. It will segfault when pos = NULL, which happens when 1422 is not in src. Additionally, dst will not be null terminated if it is smaller then the match. This can only go right if src and dst have the same size, which makes it rather pointless to do a copy as you just save pos.

Comment: I didn't want to bloat the sample too much and assumed the reader knows, that it is not a good idea to copy from a NULL pointer. It is a hint into right direction and not a bad answer. But you're right, it is not very robust.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the first and last characters' indexes of the substring you want to pick, you should do this with [strncpy](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strncpy/). See the following snippet to copy substringLength characters from the inputStr string at the given startIndex.

```
char * inputStr;
char * outputStr;

strncpy(outputStr, inputStr + startIndex, substringLength);
```

Comment: Don't forget to null terminate the copied string - because `strncpy()` won't do it for you, in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split at the location of a particular string, you can do something like this:

```
#define MAX_STRING 1024
int main() {
    char myleftBuffer[MAX_STRING]="";
    char myrightBuffer[MAX_STRING]="";
    char mystring[]="Party City 1422 Evergreen Street";
    char *start = strstr(mystring, "1422");
    if(start) {
        strcpy(myrightBuffer, start);
        strncpy(myleftBuffer, mystring, (start - mystring));
    }
    printf("%s -> %s\n", myleftBuffer, myrightBuffer);
    return;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Party City  -> 1422 Evergreen Street
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `strncpy` is *not* a particularly good choice for the task at hand. It always pads your value out to occupy the entire destination, which is generally pretty wasteful (it was originally designed for putting file names into the Unix file system; it's good for that, but not really much else).

I think I'd use `sscanf`. Assuming we always want to copy from the first digit to the end of the string, you could do something like this:

```
char street_name[256];

sscanf(input_buffer, "%*[^0-9]%255[^\n]", street_name);
```

FWIW, the `%*[^0-9]` part skips over characters until it reaches something in the range 0-9 (yes, I know it looks like a regex, but scanf and company support it too). The `*` in it means to scan but *not* assign what it finds. The `%255[^\n]` means to read and assign until the next newline in the input, or up to 255 characters, whichever comes first.

Comment: Range expressions in `%[` have implementation-defined behavior. You should use `%*[^0123456789]` or (perhaps better) `%*u`.

Comment: @R: In theory, yes. In practice, essentially the only compiler/library stupid enough to treat `0-9` as signifying `0`, `-` and `9` was Borland (and if I'm not mistaken, even they fixed this eventually). From a practical viewpoint, it's fine to use it unless you foresee porting to MS-DOS...

Comment: @R: Oh: I meant to add that you do *not* want `%*u` -- first of all, that would *not* skip over the leading letters (which you do want to skip) and if there were none there, it *would* skip over the number (which you *don't* want skipped).

Answer (score 0):

```
int split_at(const char *in, const char *match, char *buf, size_t len)
{
     char *pos;

    if( (pos = strstr(in, match)) == NULL )
        return -1; // No match
    else if( pos == in )
        return  0; // match is empty

    if( strlcpy(buf, pos, len) >= len )
        fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: match truncated: %s", buf);

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably impossible in the general case, and you would do better to get the input in seperate fields, but if thats not a option, something the following should work:

```
size_t street_extract(char* ret,size_t retsz,char* addr)
    {
    size_t i,nwrote;
    for(i=0; addr[i] ;i++)
        {
        if(addr[i]!=' ') continue; /* only check at start of word */
        i++;
        if('0' < addr[i] && addr[i] < '9') break; /* found street number */
        }
    if(!addr[i]) return -1; /* not found */

    for(nwrote=0; addr[i+nwrote] && nwrote < retsz-1 ;nwrote++)
        {
        ret[nwrote] = addr[i+nwrote];
        }

    ret[nwrote] = 0;
    while(addr[i+nwrote]) nwrote++;
    return nwrote; /* result is nwrote characters in length */
    }
```

modify and error-check as needed.